# Too much of belief in god and religion

Tags: vocabulary

Which word best describes too much belief in god and religion ?

Comment: _Religiosity_ is the noun; it doesn't mean just having religion, but having a **lot** of religion.

Comment: I favor "god-botherer"...but what kind of word are you looking for? A noun describing a person? Please provide a sentence with a blank where the word would fit.

Comment: also "piety", "fervour" or "devotion".

Comment: @Graffito in that vein, also 'zeal'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers this entry for *religiose*:

> **religiose** *adj* (1853) : RELIGIOUS; *esp* : excessively, obtrusively, or sentimentally religious — **religiosity** *n*

As this Ngram chart for the years 1750–2005 indicates, *religiose* (the blue line) remains a rare word in published English texts, but *religiosity* (the red line) has become much more common over the past century:

[image]

Comment: I was wondering  when the term assumed a negative connotation. I don't think it originally meant that: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=religious&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: @Josh61: Interesting question. The pejorative element goes pretty far back, I think. The word _religiosity_ appears with a seemingly neutral definition in _Webster's [First] International Dictionary_ (1898): "The quality of being religious; religious feeling or sentiment; religiousness." But in the _Third Collegiate Dictionary_ (1916) it carries this definition: "Quality of being religious, esp., excessively or affectedly religious; religiousness." Another word that might fit the OP's requirements is _religionist_ ("a person adhering to a religion; _esp_ : a religious zealot").

Comment: It strikes me because in Italian , French and also Spanish , I think, the term has a neutral connotation. I need to look into it. :)

Comment: @Josh61: It would be interesting to investigate whether the rise of [Christian fundamentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_fundamentalism) in the late 1800s and early 1900s had anything to do with the emergence of the (still-current) unflattering sense of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Best match I know is ***[zealotry](http://Fanatical%20and%20uncompromising%20pursuit%20of%20religious,%20political,%20or%20other%20ideals;%20fanaticism:)***:

> - fanatical and uncompromising pursuit of religious, political, or other ideals; fanaticism. (ODO)

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I believe to be some commonly known choices used signify the concept. However, it must be forewarned that in this more recent and contemporary era, they would both be easily conflated with their more figurative senses.

My preferred choice and the most easily understood would be Fanaticism:

> Fanaticism, n. Excessive enthusiasm; wild and extravagant notions of religion; religious frenzy.

Somebody who practices Fanaticism could be called a Fanatic or Fanatical, which are words which expound upon the subject further:

> [Adjective](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2238896): Wild and extravagant in opinions, particularly in religious opinions; excessively enthusiastic; possessed by a kind of frenzy. Hence we say, fanatic zeal; fanatic notions or opinions.
>
> ---
>
> [Noun](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2238897): A person affected by excessive enthusiasm, particularly on religious subjects; one who indulges wild and extravagant notions of religion, and sometimes exhibits strange motions and postures, and vehement vociferation in religious worship. Fanatics sometimes affect to be inspired or to have intercourse with superior beings.
>
> "Fanatics are governed rather by imagination than by judgment." — Stowe.

Although this dictionary accepts either spelling for either form, fanatical more commonly refers to the adjective due to the function of the suffix [-al](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-al), meaning "of or relating to" (See: The American Heritage Dictionary, 5th edition [A.H.D. 5])

Unfortunately this word is now more commonly understood to refer to any interest, rather than simply the religious ones but I still encounter use of the religious meaning, at least within the contexts of presently popular fiction, so this sense is still understood too.

Another word choice to call somebody by, which is generally less forgivable is to call such a person a [Bigot](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=bigot&use1828=on):

> Noun 1. A person who is obstinately and unreasonably wedded to a particular religious creed, opinion, practice or ritual. The word is sometimes used in an enlarged sense, for a person who is illiberally attached to any opinion, or system of belief; as "a bigot to the Mohammedan religion" [or] "a bigot to a form of government".

Unfortunately, the 'enlargened' sense has grown to be effectively the only sense now understood and has acquired a tinge of hatefulness, especially against members of any group which has become a particular target of the bigot. I almost never see this word being used to describe religion in particular.

The third option is [fundamentalism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fundamentalism)  (See: A.H.D. 5), which is the word now used to describe fanaticism and the word for such a person practicing fundamentalism would be fundamentalist. However, I do dislike this use of the word since it implies that having firm ethical principles is necessarily a bad thing, by combining fundamental with the suffixes [-ism](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=-ism&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) and [-ist](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=-ist&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) (See: [Webster's Revisued Unabridged Dictionary, 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)) to describe the theory and and practitioners of [fundamentals](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=fundamental&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on).

> Adjective : Pertaining to the foundation or basis; serving for the foundation. Hence, essential; important; as a fundamental truth or principle; a fundamental law; a fundamental sound or chord in music.
>
> ---
>
> Noun: A leading or primary principle, rule, law or article, which serves as the ground work of a system; essential part; as the fundamentals of the christian faith.

If we consider the proprietary signification of words a factor in proneness, [as Samuel Johnson does in his 1747 Plan for an English Dictionary](https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/%7Ejlynch/Texts/plan.html), a fundamentalist should, properly, not necessarily be considered religious and may be good. That would be dependent upon what are the practiced fundaments and whether their principles are virtuous or if they are not. Comparatively, being a fanatic would almost always be considered bad. However most people, linguists included, do not seem to care about the proprietary signification anymore.

---

All block-quoted references come from [The American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/) (A.D.E.L.) by Noah Webster published between 1828 and 1844.